# How to listen for a bunch of Futures without a FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have built a FutureBuilder to check Futures then redirect based on that, but as it's a FutureBuilder, *I have to return the Screen NOT ROUTING to them*.
Can somebody share an example of **how to listen for a bunch of futures without a FutureBuilder**, so I can Route with animation instead of dummy return.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
    future: Future.wait([
         firstFuture(),
         secondFuture(),
    ]),
    builder: (
       context, 
       AsyncSnapshot<List<bool>> snapshot, 
    ){

       if (!snapshot.hasData) { 
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
       }

       // If all future passed return home.
       if (snapshot.data[0] && snapshot.data[1]) 
          // Instead I want: MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeScreen());
          return HomeScreen();

       // Instead I want: MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => permissionsScreen());
       return permissionsScreen();

    }
);
```

Comment: `Future.wait()` static method waits for multiple `Future`s - the docs say: *"Waits for multiple futures to complete and collects their results."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on pskink's advice, I implemented this code which will loop and wait for a bunch of Futures to finish, then route or whatever without a FutureBuilder:

```dart
//.. inside a StatfulWidget or whatever...

// Loop thru Dependencies List(Futures) and make sure all are loaded(finished).
Future<bool> loadDependencies(List<Future<bool>> dependenciesList) async {
    bool isAllDone = true;

    // Load dependencies.
    for (Future<bool> dependency in dependenciesList) {
      bool currentDep = await dependency;
      isAllDone = isAllDone && currentDep;
      if (!isAllDone) return false; // Break if any failed.
    }

    return isAllDone;
}
```

Then call it, here's an example:

```dart
//.. inside a StatfulWidget

// Define App's Dependencies List.
final List<Future<bool>> dependenciesList = [
    someBloc.fetchData(),
];

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // Load dependencies then route once done.
  loadDependenciesAndRoute();
}

void loadDependenciesAndRoute() async {
    bool loadingStatus = await loadDependencies(dependenciesList);

    if (loadingStatus) {
      // As Context is not ready inside initState, routing using navigatorKey.
      await AppKeys.navigatorKey.currentState.push(
        Routes.home(),
      );
    } else {
      await AppKeys.navigatorKey.currentState.push(
          Routes.onLoading(),
      );
    }
}
```